# Vb.net excel oledb viewing excel file data

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, connection-string

```
Dim dir = "../Football/"
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub ViewTable_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FfilesComboBox.DisplayMember = "Text"
End Sub
Private Sub RefreshButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RefreshButton.Click
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        FfilesComboBox.Items.Add(New With {.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), .Value = file})
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FfilesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FfilesComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim viewpath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dir) & FfilesComboBox.SelectedItem & ".xlsm"
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + viewpath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;ReadOnly=True;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Teams$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    FtableDataGridView.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

I am trying to view the data of the excel file from datagridview in selected excel file from the combobox. currently i am getting this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Additional information: Operator '&' is not defined for string "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Final yea" and type 'VB$AnonymousType_0(Of String,String)'.

Comment: The error tells you whats wrong: you filled a CBO with an anonymous type,  then try to use it as if it was a ordinary string.  The CBO display should be showing you it is 2 things together.  Are you trying to save the full path, but show just the name? (ask a question)

Comment: it is actually oledb. i can save the path i want to access the path to provide the connection to Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + viewpath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;ReadOnly=True;"  what i want to achieve is when an item(eg:something.xlms) is selected from the combobox, to view data inside(something.xlms) in datagridview.

Comment: Helpful tip: when someone asks a question like `Are you trying to save the full path, but show just the name?` it is because they want to be sure what the question is before they waste any time composing an answer.  Maybe someone else can help....